# lookahead is not working with python regex and nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to extract subject (it comes just before the verb) using POS tag and regex but it failed.
Here is my function:

```
def get_SOP(sent):
 tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
 tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

 grammar = r"""
 Sub:    {(<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>*)(?=(<VB.*>?<VB.*>?))}
 Pre:  {<VB.*>?<VB.*>?}
 """
 cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
 return cp.parse(tags)
```

for the sentence:the girl is sitting in the balcony.
I get a tree with Sub:the girl Pred:is sitting and another Sub:in the balcony which is not correct so the lookahead is not working for me.
  I am using Python 3.4. and nltk 3.2.1.

Comment: What's not working? And what does your input text look like? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I cannot extract the sub I get only the pred correct.For example : sent=the girl is sitting in the balcony.I get for this regex Sub:the girl ,Pred:is sitting Sub: in the balcony which is not correct I only want to get the subject located just before the verb.So the lookahead is not working for me.Thanks

Comment: the prob with the pred I should it <VB.*><VB.*>?.Thanks anyway!